# Login to a website through an app without any WebView and then get details of that user specifically

Tags: android

For example if my website is www.medicalloginexample.com and on its Login page, there are three details that need to be filled:

1) Username Id

2) Password

3) Auto captcha

After this I press Login and it authenticates with its server. 
My question is how do I build an app that

- Allows me to input only **Username and Password** which will then autheticated with the same database
- Auto Captcha is automatically filled
- The details of the user from the website such as Name, Medical History, Medicines Prescribed all can be scrapped and updated through the app

Please guide me how to achieve the above requirements

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should think of using `OkHTTP` / `Retrofit2` to do the API login request.

What you need is the API endpoints for the login. This endpoint will probably take in `username` and `password` and the backend will verify it.

To remove captcha, I would assume that some sort of `Auth Token` will do it‘s purpose.

However, such information you usually get from the websites Backend developers (information regarding the APIs).

- [Retrofit 2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Consuming APIs with Retrofit](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

*Note that this only works if you have FTP and database access and if the server runs PHP.*

I suggest you to write an API in PHP returning JSON. Then you can send a HTTP request from your app to the server and it will return you all info you need in JSON. Parsing JSON is pretty easy in Java (there are a couple of classes and libraries available too).